# getParseData: equal_assign non-terminal missing

Tags: r, parsing

In an output of the GetParseFunction() there is missing the same parent node of equality assignment. Is that correct? 
There is non-terminal in R grammar called "equal_assign", I would expect it as a parent node of equality assignment.

Mentioned part of R grammar (from R source files "\R-3.5.1\src\main\gram.y):

`equal_assign    :    expr EQ_ASSIGN expr_or_assign          { $$ = xxbinary($2,$1,$3); }
;`

`expr_or_assign  :    expr                       { $$ = $1; }
                 |    equal_assign               { $$ = $1; }
;`

**Example:**

**test.R:** `foo = - 7`

Assume we would like to examine test.R syntax tree by getParseData:

`getParseData(parse("test.R"))`

**result:**

```
  line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent     token terminal text
1     1    1     1    3  1      3    SYMBOL     TRUE  foo
3     1    1     1    3  3      0      expr    FALSE     
2     1    5     1    5  2      0 EQ_ASSIGN     TRUE    =
8     1    7     1    9  8      0      expr    FALSE     
4     1    7     1    7  4      8       '-'     TRUE    -
5     1    9     1    9  5      6 NUM_CONST     TRUE    7
6     1    9     1    9  6      8      expr    FALSE
```

I wonder if there shouldn't be a parent node of ids 3, 2, 8, because there are not really children of the root node.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like a bug in 3.5.1, but doesn't seem to be there in the nightly builds.

Comment: New item here:  http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2018/10/03#n2018-10-03

Comment: Thank you, @user2554330.